# Cannot resolve production code in tests after Android Studio Chipmunk automatically created modules

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I'm currently using Android Studio to develop a multi-module project by test-driven-development methods. It went well until I updated my IDE to Android Studio Chipmunk from previous Bumblebee.
When I opened the project after the update, it seemed that AS automatically generated some modules for me. As you can see in the pic, those new names such as [main] and [unitTest] appeared in the project view automatically.
[modules generated automatically](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qegV.png)

After this, I found that the classes and methods of my production code could not be resolved in my test code. AS told me after I pressed Alt+Enter that I should add dependency to the main module of my production code. And it added one line in the build.gradle file: "testImplementation project(path: ':app')". After syncing the gradle build, nothing had changed and it still could not resolve methods in my production code. I can still run the tests by executing gradle test tasks, but it is weird that I cannot use production code in my test code directly.

**UPDATE:**

For further information, I think this is a problem caused by the update from Intellij 2021.1 to 2021.2, since I re-installed AS Bumblebee and all seems worked fine. I also found this issue in JetBrains YouTrack that has an exactly same problem with me. Here is the link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-275566/Class-not-found-after-intellij-upgrade-2021-1-2-2021-2

This issue remains open and I've tried some other developers' reply in this issue to delete the .iml files, but the problem remains. I think Intellij 2021.1 and 2021.2 generate different .iml file in the .idea folder.

Comment: It's a big problem. In May 2022, it's been logged at least 3 times in Google's Issue Tracker bug list:  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232441109  ,  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232284884  ,  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/232131785

Comment: @Mr-IDE Wow, that's impressive. I've googled a lot for this problem and haven't found too much people talking about it so I thought I was the only one. One reply in these links said that upgrading to gradle 7.0 or newer can solve the problem but sadly my company is using a custom gradle. So I hope guys in google can figure out how to fix this for users who are still using old version gradles.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issues in the first Android Studio Chipmunk release - all of my unit test source code was peppered with "***Cannot resolve symbol***" errors, but the code would still compile and run, and the tests would pass.

I found that I could temporarily workaround (i.e., "fix") the issue by adding a line to the `build.gradle` file like:

```
testImplementation project(path: ':shared:library:module')
```

But today I upgraded to the new Chipmunk release, with details:

```
Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
Runtime version: 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
```

And the issue no longer occurs. I'm guessing the folks working on the IntelliJ platform found and patched the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried to update my AS to the latest version I can get by "check updates", which should also be Chipmunk Patch 1, but that issue still occurred. It still said "cannot resolve symbol", though the tests could run without any exceptions, it could be really hard to write tests with no auto-fill-ins. And the whole screen of red class names was kinda annoying. I could only keep working on Bumblebee, which did not have that problem.  BTW adding that dependency to build.gradle worked for some of my modules, but others not. Weird!